# How do you setup project to use ini file in Developer Studio?

Tags: eclipse, progress-4gl, openedge

I use a ini file to setup fonts and colors (instead of the registry). I have linked the ini file like this:

```
Properties->ProgressOpenEdge->Startup parameters->
"-basekey ini -ininame C:\somepath\ini\progress11.ini"
```

If I make a small run file (and press run) the ini file is correctly loaded:

```
run start.w
```

But if I press run on the start file the ini file is not loaded (getting font errors). How to setup eclipse to load the ini file correct?

Edit: Had to have 2 more reputation to show images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "run" button there's a "downarrow". Click on that, and then click on "run configurations" - that'll enable you to set the startup parameters for the run button.

[image]

Comment: Correct, nice thank you. In addition: On "Startup" tab choose "Ini file:" location.